# php str_replace() for / and &

Tags: php, xml, str-replace, feed, ampersand

We have created an xml feed in Magento for some products from different categories. Some products have a name with a &, or the name of the brand is with a /. When we generate the feed, the feed gives an error.

[image: xml error]

In previous feeds we've used this line of code:

```
<name><? return str_replace("&", "&amp;", "{name}"); ?></name>
```

to turn the `&` into a `&amp;` and this worked. Now we need to do the same thing with the `/`. We need to turn the `/` into 'and' or something like that.

There are 2 (different) lines of codes in our xml feed where we can paste the str_replace:

```
<? if ("{name}" != "") return "<li><b>Name:</b> {name}</li>"; ?>
```

and

```
<name>{name}</name>
```

Where should the str_replace be pasted?

Comment: change `<? return str_replace("&", "&amp;", "{name}"); ?>` to `<? return str_replace(array('&', '/') , array('&amp;','and'), "{name}"); ?>`. is `"{name}"` part correct? [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) accepts array for search and replace.

Comment: You can use str_replace at two times one for "&" and one for "/".

Comment: @RaghbendraNayak why 2 times when `str_replace` can do it in one go.

Comment: <naam><? if ("{merk}" != "Merknaam") return "{merk} "; ?><? return str_replace("&", "&amp;", "{name}"); ?></naam>
This is the full code that maked the previous feeds work. Naam is the name of the row

Comment: @bansi Yes we can do it in one go also. If he is getting any problem syntactically then he can use it twice too.

Comment: @bansi <serie>{serie}<? return str_replace(array('&', '/') , array('&amp;','and'), "{serie}"); ?></serie>
Should this code do the trick?

Comment: doesn't look to me like pure php, may be some templating engine. you should be ideally be using str_replace where you assign value to `"{name}"` look for some code like `"{name}" = ....`

Comment: there is no harm in trying.

Comment: @bansi Yeah the feed is generated in Magento, maybe that's why. <serie> is a property of a product, just like <name> was in the previous feeds. In this case the name of the series of a couple of couches is 'Modulair / MixMatch', and i need the feed to turn it into 'Modulair and MixMatch'

Comment: Why not use DOMDocument or SimpleXML to build XML documents?  That's what they're for after all, and they're more robust than string concatenation ever would be.

Answer (score -1):

I got the xml working.

```
<serie><? return str_replace(array('&', '/') , array('&amp;','and'), "{serie}"); ?></serie>
```

did the trick for me.

The {serie} on the end of the code was the problem. I don't understand why it worked in the previous feeds, but u don't hear me complaining haha.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use str_replace in this case, there is htmlentities function for this purpose: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer